# How to append content of one textfile to another textfile using batchscript?

Tags: text, batch-file

How to create a simple batchscript in windows that will take the contents of one txt file and will append it to the end of another textfile

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type command can be used to concatenate files. Try

```
type file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Brett's answer works well. Another alternative is

```
copy file1.txt + file2.txt /b
```

You can append any number of files with this syntax by adding additional files.

The `/b` option prevents the `<ctrl-Z>` end-of-file marker from being appended to the end of the file after the copy.